# Is [math.pow] a good tag for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've started a tag spree for [math.pow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math.pow).

Is it a good idea or should I stop?

There are tons of questions (surely more that 100) that are related to that exact method and all of its peculiarity so I think it deserves a separate tag.

What is your opinion?

Comment: Presumably, you mean Math.Pow in some language that has such a method. Shouldn't that language be part of the tag?

Comment: I've added JavaScript, Java and C# in the tag wiki

Comment: I don't understand this at all,  Why is Math.Pow() so different to any other lib function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that a question will be helped by adding the tag then add it.

However, please bear in mind the following:

1. Don't go on retagging spree. The last thing we want is for the home page to be flooded by edits to old questions. Spread your edits out over a few days.
2. Don't engage in a rollback war if others disagree and remove the tag.

Ultimately the community will decide whether the tag is useful or not by either accepting your edits or rolling them back.

Comment: I've been searching, but couldn't find consensus for method-specific tags (it's a .NET BLC method, `Math.Pow()`). Is there?

Comment: @CodeCaster - I don't think there is a consensus. However, as I said in my answer, if you think it's useful add it. The worst that can happen is that your edits will be rolled back.

Answer (score 10):

It's a terrible tag. We don't need a tag for every API method; there is nothing startlingly special about this API method that changes that; and we don't need a tag that only covers O(100) questions either. Please don't do this.

NB you haven't even spelt the function name correctly.

Comment: And if the power-function is central enough to a question to merit tagging, there's [tag:pow] already.